# remove specific characters from text file string

Tags: python, file, variables, python-3.x

I have a text file with the following line in it:  ('larry', 3, 100)
I need to assign the three parts of it to different variables using a
method close to what I have below. So far I can split it down, 
but I **cannot remove the brackets and apostrophes** from the result.
I have tried other solutions on stackover for hours to no avail...

```
filecontent = filename.read().strip().split(',')

for i in filecontent:
    name = filecontent[0]
    weeks_worked = filecontent[1]
    weekly_payment = filecontent[2] 

print ("name:" + name)
print ("weeks worked:" + weeks_worked)
print ("weekly payment:" + weekly_payment)
```

gives the result:

name:('larry'

weeks worked:3

weekly payment:100)

**How do I make it show just:**

name:larry

weeks worked:3

weekly payment:100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) here, which will convert the string to a tuple:

```
import ast
filecontent = ast.literal_eval(filename.read().strip())
```

You also don't need a for-loop, you can also just do:

```
name, weeks_worked, weekly_payment = filecontent
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex either after or before split.

```
    filecontent = filename.read().strip().split(',')

    for i in filecontent:
        name = re.sub(r'\(|\)|\'','',filecontent[0])
        weeks_worked =  re.sub(r'\(|\)|\'','',filecontent[1])
        weekly_payment = re.sub(r'\(|\)|\'','',filecontent[1])
```

OR I would prefer doing this

```
   filecontent = re.sub(r'\(|\)|\'','',filename.read().strip()).split(',')
```

And then do your usual stuff.